# How to use param values inside for loop

Tags: shell-script, parameter

I am running my script as `script.sh 12345 12346 12347`

```
for z in 1..$(seq 1 $#);
do
    echo "param $z is $($(echo $z))"; //Line 4
done;
```

I am expecting output as below:

```
param 1 is 12345
param 2 is 12346
param 3 is 12347
```

Guess, I am missing something in Line 4.

Comment: Which shell are you using?

Comment: ```GNU bash, version 4.4.12(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem with `$($(echo $z))` is that it expands, first to `$(1)` (if `$z` is 1) and then the shell tries to run `1` as a command.

---

Assuming `bash`:

```
params=( "$@" )

for (( i = 0; i < ${#params[@]}; ++i )); do
    printf 'Param %d is "%s"\n' "$i" "${params[i]}"
done
```

Running it:

```
$ bash script.sh a b c
Param 0 is "a"
Param 1 is "b"
Param 2 is "c"
```

Or, with `/bin/sh`:

```
i=0
while [ "$#" -gt 0 ]; do
    printf 'Param %d is "%s"\n' "$i" "$1"
    i=$(( i + 1 ))
    shift
done
```

Running that:

```
$ /bin/sh script.sh a b c
Param 0 is "a"
Param 1 is "b"
Param 2 is "c"
```

That's if you really need to explicitly enumerate them.  Usually one would just loop over `"$@"`:

```
for param in "$@"; do
    printf 'Param: "%s"\n' "$param"
    # do other thing with "$param" here
done
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for z in 1..$(seq 1 $#);
```

That would expand to `1..1`, `2`, `3` for three parameters. `seq` already prints the numbers as distinct words, and `for` can't really generate lists of numbers. Brace expansion can generate lists of numbers, the syntax is `{1..3}`, but in Bash it doesn't support variables inside it.

So this could be written as

```
for z in $(seq $#) ; do ...                  # or 
for (( z=1 ; z <= $# ; z++ )) ; do ...
```

or with braces in ksh or zsh:

```
for z in {1..$#} ; do  ...
```

If you want to refer to a variable indirectly, you can use `${!var}` (in Bash) where `var` holds the *name* of the variable, so e.g.

```
echo "param number $z is ${!z}"
```

Alternatively, you could use the slice notation on `$@` (should work in Bash/ksh/zsh):

```
echo "param number $z is ${@:z:1}"
```

---

But really, just using `for x in "$@"` to loop over the values may be considered more idiomatic. The numbering is also rather simple to add without any shell-specific features:

```
i=1
for x in "$@" ; do 
    echo "param $i is $x"
    i=$((i+1))     
done
```

Comment: I realized that :)